# Blazor EditForm bind from List

Tags: forms, blazor

I'm trying to make a page to edit customer data.

The customer object has a list of phonenumbers(string) , because most have a landline and cellphone.
I can't seem to find a way to put this into an editform. I tried using a foreach loop, but it can't bind to this.
I also tried to use a local copy in the loop and bind to that. That works, but i can't retrieve the changes after the submit button is pressed.
What am i doing wrong ? What is the proper way to do this ? I can't seem to find any tutorial that covers this.

I have recreated my page to the minimal that does the same thing:

This is my Customer class

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // arbitrary extra fields
        public List<string> phoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

 public class CustomerService
    {
        Customer jeff;

        public CustomerService()
        {
            jeff = new Customer
            {
                Name = "Jeff",
                phoneNumber = new List<string> { "123456", "654321" },
            };
        }

        public Customer getCustomer()
        {
   
            return jeff;
        }

        public void setCustomer(Customer cust)
        {
            jeff = cust;
        }
    }
```

And my page

```
<EditForm Model="@customer" OnSubmit="@submitChanges">

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@customer.Name" /><br/>
    <!-- How do i link the multiple phonenumbers-->

    @foreach(string phone in customer.phoneNumber)
    {
        //this does not compile
        //<InputText @bind-Value="@phone"/>

        //this compiles but i can't find how to acces the data afterward ???
        string temp = phone;
        <InputText @bind-Value="@temp"/>

    }

    @for(int i=0;i<customer.phoneNumber.Count();i++)
    {
        //this compiles but chrashed at page load
        // <InputText @bind-Value="@customer.phoneNumer[i]"/>
    }


    <button type="submit">submit</button>
      
</EditForm>
```

###### Code Section

```
@code {        

    Customer customer;
   
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        customer = _data.getCustomer();           
    }

    private void submitChanges()
    {
        _data.setCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Wolf, today I've read about the  [ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types) which is used instead of the *DataAnnotationsValidator* component

> To validate the bound model's entire object graph, including
>   collection- and complex-type properties

Emphasis on including *collection*. Consequently, I searched for a sample implementing a collection in EditForm, but could not find. After exerting some efforts I succeeded to do that. Here's the code:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<EditForm Model="@customer" OnSubmit="@submitChanges">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <p>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="customer.Name" /><br />
    </p>
    @foreach (var phone in customer.phones)
    {
        <p>
            <InputText @bind-Value="phone.PhoneNumber" /> 
        </p>

     }

     <p>
         <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </p>

    </EditForm>

 <div>
    <p>Edit  customer</p>

    <p>@customer.Name</p>
    @foreach (var phone in customer.phones)
    {
        <p>@phone.PhoneNumber</p>

    }

</div>
@code {

Customer customer;



protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    customer = new Customer();

}
private void submitChanges()
{
    // _data.setCustomer(customer);
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "jeff";
    //[ValidateComplexType]
    public List<Phone> phones { get; } = new List<Phone>() { new Phone 
     {PhoneNumber = "123456" }, new Phone {PhoneNumber = "654321" }};
}

public class Phone
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, that was what i feared.
In the actual application, I'm using a displaymodel, i will do what you suggested there.

Comment: I ended up using a single string in the displaymodel. Seperating each with newline, and a InputTextArea in the page. Seems to work well enough.
Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: looking at the code you have now provided, i see what i did wrong.
I was trying to bind to the iterator in the foreach loop. But that can't be changed. When linking to the child elements of the iterator , it does work. I would never have found this on my own. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
use     
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: initial;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?